# Sending Pdf, created with html2pdf, via Mail

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm trying to send a document using eKoopmans html2pdf ([new-api-branch](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf/tree/new-api)) script via email. But since I'm not a trained programmer, I'm having a couple of problems with it.

Here is my code so far

```
<head>
<!-- Stuff that goes here -->
<script src="opt/html2pdf-new-api/dist/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cmd").click(function(){
    var signaturefilename = $('#auftragsnummer').val();
    var element = document.getElementById('PDFcontent');
    var opt ={
      filename: signaturefilename+'.pdf',
      image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
    }
    html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).save();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" id="PDFcontent">
  <!-- Contents that should be converted to pdf -->
  </div>
</body>
```

I can save the file, using the value of an input field as filename, without any problems. Everything I need is in the PDF and it displays fine.

As I've read in one of the issues [here](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf/issues/14#issuecomment-362804538), it is possible to get that PDF data and pass it to phpmailer. But I have to be honest here, I have no clue on how to do that. I tried to do

```
html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).toDataURL();
```

instead, but that just gave me an error.

What I want to do in the end is as follows. I want to create that PDF and attach it to an email. That email should also have the value of the field with the id="auftragsnummer" + some text as subject.

I think I would need to get some kind of string, store in a var and pass that to phpmailer. I probably need to decode it back inside the php-script, but as I've said, my knowledge is limited...

If someone could help me, on how to attach that PDF to phpmailer, or somehow save it on the server, that would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help. Best regards

Comment: Hi Jochen ! Did you find a way to do it ? i'm about to do the same